# triple integral spherical coordinate

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spheres

I have a problem converting this question into a spherical form.
$∫∫∫ z/√(x^2+y^2+z^2)dxdydz$  where R is the interior of a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2z$

the limits of integration I found are:
0≤r≤2cosθ
0≤θ≤ π
0≤φ≤2 π
[image: The sign of limit I used may be different so this is what I follow]

After converting this is my integrand
$∫∫∫ rcosθr^2sinθ/√2rcosθ drdθdφ$ with limit given above.
But this doesn't give me the right answer. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure in the $x^2+y^2+y^2=2z$?

Comment: sorry, it should be z^2.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the sphere can be rewritten as $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1$. Thus the sphere has center $(0,0,1)$ and radius $1$. In particular, it is not the sphere in the picture. Since the sphere lies above the $xy$-plane, you should have
 $$0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Also the denominator $\sqrt{2 r \cos \theta}$ in the integrand looks wrong. The denominator is just $r$ since $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe , instead of $$ z=r cos φ    $$ 
 $$ z=1+r cos φ    $$

Then the boundaries for r would be from 0 to 1